# ComboBox event trigger happening even when user doesn't select item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, event-handling

I need to catch an event when a user selects an item from a combo box. After reading some answers here on StackOverflow I used this method
(XAML):

```
SelectionChanged="LocationBox_SelectionChanged"
```

And the event handler in C#:

```
private void LocationBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

The problem is that this event handler is getting tripped numerous times as the ComboBox is being built dynamically and not when a user selects an item. By the way, this method *does work correctly* when a user selects an item. The problem is all of these extraneous events.

I want the event handler to be called only when a user selects an item from the combobox. I do not want the event handler to be called when the combobox is being built dynamically before it is displayed. It appears that every time an item is added to the combobox it is tripping the event handler. I want the event handler to be tripped IFF a human being makes a selection from the combobox.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't really described the problem but just a symptom. Why is it a problem that the event is triggered and what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: You still haven't explained why it's a problem.

Comment: It's a problem because when it falsely reports a user event my code would like to do something with the user selected index. However, since the user didn't actually select anything the event, and subsequent index, is wrong causing a crash.

Comment: Create a bool called (e. g.) `IsLoading`.  If that bool is true, then immediately exit the event handler.  Another alternative is to not wire up the handler in XAML but in code when you're ready to handle the events.

Comment: That's a pretty fugly way of dealing with it. Isn't there a standard call that trips IFF a user selects an item from a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about the selectionChanged signal.
You can always use [QObject: blockSignals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals) during QComboBox editing?

Comment: QT? This is in WPF.

Comment: Bugger. Apologies @zetar - will have to check my filters and read the tags :(

Answer (score -1):

> It's a problem because when it falsely reports a user event my code would like to do something with the user selected index. However, since the user didn't actually select anything the event, and subsequent index, is wrong causing a crash.

Just `return` from your event handler immediately in case `SelectedItem == null` or `SelectedIndex == -1`.

Comment: SelectedIndex is NOT returning null. It is returning 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1.

Comment: That's what i wrote, pay attention.

Comment: Because I need to know if the user selected item 0. You do understand that index = 0 is a legitimate index value, right?

Comment: Yes,  but you should only get those if you don't prevent a default selection (preset index).

Comment: Also: If you handler code crashes for **valid** indices something is wrong with your code.